# MVC If statement in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have problem with IF statement inside MVC View. I am trying to use it for creating row for every three items.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    @if (ViewBag.Articles != null)
    {
      int nmb = 0;
      foreach (var item in ViewBag.Articles)
      {
        if (nmb % 3 == 0) { 
          <div class="row">  
        }    
        <a href="@Url.Action("Article", "Programming", new { id = item.id })">    
          <div class="tasks">    
            <div class="col-md-4">    
              <div class="task important">
                <h4>@item.Title</h4>
                <div class="tmeta">
                  <i class="icon-calendar"></i> @item.DateAdded - Pregleda:@item.Click  
                  <i class="icon-pushpin"></i> Authorrr  
                </div>    
              </div>    
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        if (nmb % 3 == 0) { 
          </div>
        }
      }
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so where is nmb increment? i mean how nmb will ++ ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You only need to prefix an `if` statement with `@` if you're not already inside a razor code block.

Edit:  You have a couple of things wrong with your code right now.

You're declaring `nmb`, but never actually doing anything with the value.  So you need figure out what that's supposed to actually be doing.  In order to fix your code, you need to make a couple of tiny changes:

```
@if (ViewBag.Articles != null)
{
    int nmb = 0;
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Articles)
    {
        if (nmb % 3 == 0)
        {
            @:<div class="row"> 
        }

        <a href="@Url.Action("Article", "Programming", new { id = item.id })">
            <div class="tasks">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="task important">
                        <h4>@item.Title</h4>
                        <div class="tmeta">
                            <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
                                @item.DateAdded - Pregleda:@item.Click
                            <i class="icon-pushpin"></i> Authorrr
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        if (nmb % 3 == 0)
        {
            @:</div>
        }
    }
}
```

The important part here is the `@:`.  It's a short-hand of `<text></text>`, which is used to force the razor engine to render text.

One other thing, the HTML standard specifies that `a` tags can only contain inline elements, and right now, you're putting a `div`, which is a block-level element, inside an `a`.

Comment: I set @ in first IF and I needed for item, URl  and this command also so I put there again..  and it's all looks good except third IF ,  if there is no @ then it's shown as text only. And if I put @ before third IF  I got errors

Comment: @zire Updated my answer again.  That should fix it for you.

Comment: John H.   Thank you very much! this work now... nmb I will use it for loop increasing nmb++.

Comment: how do you close the <div> if total count isn't evenly divisible by 3?

Comment: @jplara Do you mean, `if (nmb % 3 != 0)`?

Comment: i think that should be added outside of the foreach, to make sure the html rendered is always correct.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you use html syntax you have to start the next razor statement with a @.  So it should be @if ....